# Ruby net/ssh is not running bash commands in background

Tags: ruby, bash, ssh, net-ssh

I am having a hard time running bash commands in background from a Ruby script.

For this question, I am using a simplified example.

This is how commands are working as expected when I run them from PuTTY.

[running basch commands in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FManZ.png)
(click to see the picture, because StackOverlow is not allowing me to show pictures yet)

Now, I try to replicate this from Ruby, using this little script shown below:

[ruby script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLinG.png)
(click to see the picture, because StackOverlow is not allowing me to show pictures yet)

This is the outout I get when I run such a Ruby script:

[script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z19Qm.png)
(click to see the picture, because StackOverlow is not allowing me to show pictures yet)

For your analysis, here is the transcription of the Ruby script:

```
require 'net/ssh'
net_remote_ip = '74.****122'
ssh_username = 'bots'
ssh_password = 'San*****'
get_ssh_port = '22'
ssh = Net::SSH.start(net_remote_ip, ssh_username, :password => ssh_password, :port => get_ssh_port)
s = "bash --login -c 'sleep 600' &"
print "run (#{s})... "
stdout = ssh.exec!(s)
puts "done (#{stdout.strip})"
ssh.close
exit(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the future please try to avoid using images, as they block search engines from finding results, and also makes it harder for people to copy code or error messages for debugging purposes. Best is to always paste as much as possible as text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect both stdout and stderr somewhere else than the terminal, otherwise `exec!` will hang waiting for process output.

This is the simplest solution I found:

```
ssh.exec!("sleep 600 &> /dev/null &")
```

`&>` redirects both stdin and stderr at the same time.
If you want to redirect the output for logging, you can do so separately if you like:

```
ssh.exec!("command 2> error.log > output.log &")
```

Comment: Thank you! 

Here is how my code looks like now.

s = "bash --login -c 'sleep 600' >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
print "run (#{s})... "
stdout = ssh.exec!(s)
puts "done (#{stdout.strip})"